# file in a realtime system

Tags: powershell, informatica

I have a scenario where MANY flat files are created at the in real time(count of files is dynamic)
I need to load only those files which are completely written

I need a script logic or anything in Informatica by which I can check if a file is being written or not

My Source is a JMS and the workflow creating files is a infinite run which reads data at real time and writes it to file.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a list of files you can obtain an write lock on.

```
Get-ChildItem *.* | foreach {
 try  {
       [IO.File]::OpenWrite($_.fullname).close()
       $_
      }

    catch { }
 }
```

If the application has finished writing to the file and closed it, you'll be able to get a write lock and the Try block will output that fileinfo object to the pipeline. If it's still open and being written to, the `[IO.File]::OpenWrite($_.fullname)` will throw an error, drop to the catch block (which does nothing), and move on to the next one.